# OpenCart Cart Information Decryption

Tags: php, database, encryption, opencart

I am developing an android app for opencart user. I need cart information decoded and identify product id quantity etc from oc_customer table. 
I tried this

```
$sql = "SELECT cart FROM oc_customer WHERE email='an registered user email';";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    var_dump(unserialize(base64_decode($row['cart'])));
}
```

I am getting this error

```
unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 36 bytes
```

Can anyone give me an clue how can I get this done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Based on previous questions, I assume you are using OpenCart 3.0.2.0).

To get the customer's cart contents, get the customer's id based on his email from `oc_customers` table, then look up that customer id in the `oc_cart` table. (This is how it is done in OpenCart 2.3+; the cart field of the oc_customers table was used in older versions of OpenCart.)

Comment: There is no oc_cart table. There is a column called cart in customer table

Comment: oc_cart table has been there since at least 2.3.0.2.

Comment: Thanks for that information. I was using a previous one. However, I solved my problem. Please edit your answer a little bit.

Comment: actually I am facing another problem. I am working on Version 2.0.1.1 and upgrading version is not my option. I want to add products on chart. I observed the pattern and inserted value in oc_customer table's cart column but when I visit the sop site and login to check my cart, it shows empty and cart column is also reset. How can I update cart value by PHP and changes works in site cart list?

Answer (score 0):

Aftetr a several research, I found that I wrongfully was decoding the full text of cart column.
Later, instead of decoding the full text, decoding only double quoted text and unserializing that gave me an array containing product_id.

Moreover, Opencart has a separated oc_cart table without these complication. Using version 2.3+ avoids all these decoding

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to use `base64_decode()` to parse cart information. just use

```
unserialize(($row['cart']);
```

Comment: No. Only unserialize gives error `Error at offset 0 of 44`